# Is this the right way to add items to NSCombobox in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm Delphi programmer and very new to Cocoa.
at first I tried this :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    int i;
    NSString *mystr;
    for (i=1;i<=24;i++)
    {
      [comboHour addItemWithObjectValue:i];
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. Then I tried to search on Google but no luck.
After experimenting about 30 min, I come with this:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    int i;
    NSString *mystr;
    for (i=1;i<=24;i++)
    {
        mystr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [comboHour addItemWithObjectValue:mystr];
        //[mystr dealloc];
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the right way to do that ?
2. Do I always need to alloc new
   NSString to change its value from
   integer ?
3. When I uncomment [mystr dealloc],
   why it won't run ?
4. Does it cause memory leak to alloc
   without dealloc ?
5. Where can I find basic tutorial like
   this on internet ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do I always need to alloc new NSString to change its value from integer ?

Generally yes; however, there are more convenient ways to create strings (and many other types of objects) than using `alloc` and `init` (see autorelease pools below)

You can pass any Objective-C object type to `addItemWithObjectValue:`, including `NSString` and `NSNumber` objects.  Both classes have a number of convenient class methods you can use to create new instances, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
{
    [comboHour addItemWithObjectValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

> When I uncomment [mystr dealloc], why it won't run ?

Never call `dealloc`.  Use `release` instead.

Cocoa objects are reference counted, like COM objects in Delphi.  Like COM, you call `release` when you're finished with an object.  When an object has no more references it is automatically deallocated.

Unlike COM, Cocoa has "autorelease pools", which allows you to, for example, create a new NSString instance without having to worry about calling `release` on it.

For example: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 123]` creates an "autoreleased" string instance.  You don't have to `release` it when you're done.  This is true of all methods that return an object, except `new` and `init` methods.

> Does it cause memory leak to alloc without dealloc ?

Yes, unless you're using garbage collection.

> Where can I find basic tutorial like this on internet ?

See [Practical Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=24;i++)
    {
        NSString *mystr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [comboHour addItemWithObjectValue:mystr];
        [mystr release];
    }
}
```

You can use `NSNumber` instead of `NSString`, which might be preferable depending on your context.

You do need to create a new object everytime, because `addItemWithObjectValue:` is expecting an object rather than a primitive.

You can create a new object (e.g. `NSString), via two methods:

1. Using alloc/init, like how you did it initially.  Such initializations require the release of the object once it isn't required anymore in the allocation scope, using `release` rather than `dealloc`.
2. Using `stringWithFormat:` factory methods that use auto release pool to release themselves "automatically".  The code would look like:

   ```
   -(void)awakeFromNib
   {
       int i;
       for (i=1; i <= 24; i++) {
           NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
           [comboHour addItemWithObjectValue:s];
       }
   }
   ```

   However, it is recommended not to use such construction within loops.

For memory issues, check out the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted and your stated experience level, I recommend going through Apple's [Currency Converter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html) tutorial if you haven't already.  It's the standard Cocoa tutorial every beginner should read.  Fundamentals like interacting with IBOutlets are covered.